# mutate if feature exists else NA_real_

Tags: r, dplyr

A dataframe:

```
exdf <- data.frame(
  a = 1:3,
  b = c(2,2,2)
)
```

Sometimes b is present, in which case one can do this:

```
exdf %>% mutate(c = a / b)
```

But, sometimes feature b will not be present, in which case:

```
exdf %>% select(-b) %>% mutate(c = a / b)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `c`.
x object 'b' not found
ℹ Input `c` is `a/b`.
```

I want to tell `dplyr` to try the mutation, else if something goes wrong just make new feature c all `NA_real_` as opposed to `a / b`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a condition with `if/else` on `exists`

```
library(dplyr)
exdf %>%
     select(-b) %>% 
     mutate(c  = if(exists('b')) a/b else NA_real_)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set up a simple if else statement within `mutate` which checks whether the column name is in the data.frame or not.

```
> exdf %>% 
... dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
... dplyr::mutate(q = ifelse("b" %in% colnames(.), a/b, NA_real_))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     q
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2   0.5
2     2     2   1  
3     3     2   1.5
```

```
> exdf %>%
... dplyr::select(-b) %>%
... dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
... dplyr::mutate(q = ifelse("b" %in% colnames(.), a/b, NA_real_))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise: 
      a     q
  <int> <dbl>
1     1    NA
2     2    NA
3     3    NA
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it does work! Question - why did we need to use rowwise()?

Comment: I (think) it's because ``/`` doesn't work in a vectorised way in ``dplyr``, so we have to tell it to perform the division on each row separately, rather than setting the entire new column as the first ``a`` divided by the first ``b``.